# Vue - Why setup with reactive when you can do it easily with data option?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I am currently building a login for a Vue app. In a tutorial (02/2021) I see that the colleague creates a setup method and imports a Vue reactive object into the component. Just to collect the form data! Can't this just be done with the data method?

**HTML / Login Component**

```html
<template>
  <form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
    <div class="container">
      <input v-model="data.username" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required />
      <input v-model="data.password" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required />
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
      {{ data }}
    </div>

  </form>
</template>
```

**1. New variant of databinding? Is that really necessary?**

```js
import {reactive} from 'vue';

export default {
    name: 'Login',
    setup() {
        const data = reactive({
            email: '',
            username: ''
        })

        return {
            data
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Old and easy variant**

```js
export default {
    name: 'Login',
    data() {
        return {
            data: {
                email: '',
                username: ''
            },
            
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: so, you're asking about `options API` vs `composition API`? Personally, I find composition API (the so called new variant) far easier to work with - even easier using `<script setup>` in a SFC - but - that's just opinion, nobody is forcing you to use the so called "new" variant - note, the `<script setup>` version of your code is `import {reactive} from 'vue'; const data = reactive({ email: '', username: ''});` ... how easy is that!!!

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for your comment and the valuable information. Now I also know what it is called. I am now curious to have a look at the new composition Api :-). In your opinion, are there any advantages worth mentioning that speak for the new api?

Comment: @JaromandaX Did I understand that correctly. That `<script setup>` already does the import of the reactive object automatically?

Comment: if that's what you understood, then you read my comment wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` field is an option in Options API where you can declare reactive data that can be used directly inside template or accessed in other hooks using `this` where everything in this API is organized by option `data`, `methods`, `computed` ... and the component features are overlapped, but in Composition API the code is organized by feature that can be extracted and reused across many logics and components.

In Vue 3 the options API is still supported, but it's recommended to use the composition one especially with `script setup` :

```html
<script setup>
import {reactive} from 'vue'; //can be auto imported in Nuxt or using auto import plugin in Vue SPA

const data = reactive({
            email: '',
            username: ''
        })
</script>
```