# using nuxt with vue 3 without using composition api

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I want to do a project by nuxt and vue but I have a question that can I use nuxt with Vue3 without using composition API?

Comment: Vue 3 still supports options api

Comment: I answered a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/73658625/8172857 this morning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you totally can.

Composition API is an opt-in. You may see a lot of composition API examples but you can totally use Options API still.

Comment: Is it possible to tell me how to use nuxt with vue3 without using composition api?

Comment: @MohammadGhiasvand have you already worked with Nuxt 2?

Comment: Yes @BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: So, you could do the same with Nuxt 3

Comment: @MohammadGhiasvand just write your usual code as you did with Nuxt2. Using `script` and not `script setup`, that's all.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim  so can I use nuxt 2 with vue 3 (without using composition api) or I have to use it with vue2?

Comment: @MohammadGhiasvand you will be using Nuxt3, with Vue3 but with no composition API. Go to the VueJS documentation and select Options API on the top left to see how to write regular Options API.